# Someone hacked my php website and access database

Tags: php

One day ago, one person hacked my whole database and access all the database tables. He took some its screenshots and send me one by one to showoff. First I can change all the godaddy password and apply 2 layer authentication but its useless. He again access my database and said he put backdoor on my website and any time when he wants can access my database.

I got very serious issue because database contain very important data. I have changed the my whole hosting plan and shift to another one but in morning I saw he again has access to my server and he added a new user on database with itself. I do not know whats the issue. I even do not know on which php file he's getting access to my database even I have changed the hosting company.

How's it possible when I have changed the hosting company and he's again get the access of my database on his command prompt may be. Even though its difficult to get new hosting domain because its also new.

some of my db code

```
<?php
require '../connect.php';
                    error_reporting(0);
                    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
                    {
                        $uname = $_POST['uname'];
                        $service = $_POST['service'];
                      $check = "SELECT * FROM Logins WHERE username='$uname'";
                      $checks = mysqli_query($con,$check);
                      $chk = mysqli_num_rows($checks);
                      if($chk == 1)
                      {
                        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($checks)) 
                        {
                          $acctype = $row['logintype'];
                        }
                        if ($service == "Sim Data") 
                        {
                          if ($acctype=="local") 
                          {
                            $price = "50";
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            $price = "10";
                          }
                        }
                        elseif ($service == "Nadra Data") 
                        {
                          if ($acctype=="local") 
                          {
                            $price = "300";
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            $price = "200";
                          }
                        }
                        elseif ($service == "Call Data Record") 
                        {
                          if ($acctype=="local") 
                          {
                            $price = "1200";
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            $price = "1000";
                          }
                        }
                        elseif ($service == "Cnic Color Copy") 
                        {
                          if ($acctype=="local") 
                          {
                            $price = "150";
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            $price = "100";
                          }
                        }
                        elseif ($service == "Live Location") 
                        {
                          if ($acctype=="local") 
                          {
                            $price = "600";
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            $price = "400";
                          }
                        }
                        elseif ($service == "IMEI Tracing") 
                        {
                          if ($acctype=="local") 
                          {
                            $price = "1000";
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            $price = "600";
                          }
                        }
                        elseif ($service == "Other") 
                        {
                          if ($acctype=="local") 
                          {
                            $price = "100";
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            $price = "100";
                          }
                        }
                        elseif ($service == "Nadra Special") 
                        {
                          if ($acctype=="local") 
                          {
                            $price = "20";
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            $price = "20";
                          }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          $price = "Wrong";
                        }



                        $in = "INSERT INTO newdata(Username,service,Profit,Status) VALUES('$uname','$service','$price','Processing')";
                        $ins = mysqli_query($con,$in);
                        $msg = "Order has been booked";
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        $msg = "Username not  found";
                      }
                    }

?>
```

Comment: Have you checked your local machine for anything that might be causing this?

Comment: yes, I have checked thats no issue on my machine

Comment: May be he's using sqlmap for accessing my database, but I have checked my website sql injection, its not working on my end.

Comment: You have changed your hosting company and still having issues with security. That means it's probably (to 99,5%) the code of the system that is the main issue. Please show some parts of your code that is related to your db so we can try to identify what's going on.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I have added. kindly check it

Comment: You're wideopen to SQL injections. I'm sorry, but anyone with little knowledge how they work would be able to hack your system. Use prepared statements!

Comment: But when I have used ' " and alert javascript on my website input field. it does not show me any sql injection error. Can you please guide me how it hacked

Comment: Just google SQL Injections: I don't always recommend W3Schools but they explain SQL Injections very well: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: sql injection only works on that php pages which has input fields or works on all??

Comment: sql injections are most relevant on user input fields yes.

Comment: @MuhammadUsama You state that your database contains "very important data". If this is actually the case you should probably learn computer security principles and best practices before exposing this data to the internet again. Additionally I would look into any data protection laws in your country to ensure that you don't have to report a breach or similar.

Comment: @PiRocks related to my clients. Important for me